# Loading overlay for a single column

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I would like to show a loading spinner for a single column, while data for that column is being fetched.

AG-Grid's loading overlay works only for the whole table.

Is there a way to adjust it for a single column?
Otherwise, what would a be good way to have a custom implementation?